# How to configure role permissions for a module in suitecrm

Tags: roles, suitecrm

I'm configuring a role to access just the records it owns. The problem is that the users are not allowed to create records

The configuration I set was "own" for edit, list and view.

What should I do to allow the users to create records?

Comment: In OOTB suitecrm, edit and create are treated like one. You will need to disable edit in order to restrict users from creating records within any module.